# Creating a list of most popular posts of the past week - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, widget

I have created a widget for my Wordpress platform that displays the most popular posts of the week. However, there is an issue with it. It counts the most popular posts from **Monday**, not the past 7 days. For instance, this means that on Tuesday, it will only include posts from Tuesday and Monday.

Here is my widget code:

```
<?php class PopularWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    function PopularWidget(){
        $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Displays Popular Posts');
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300);
        parent::WP_Widget(false,$name='ET Popular Widget',$widget_ops,$control_ops);
    }

  /* Displays the Widget in the front-end */
    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? 'Popular This Week' : $instance['title']);
        $postsNum = empty($instance['postsNum']) ? '' : $instance['postsNum'];
        $show_thisweek = isset($instance['thisweek']) ? (bool) $instance['thisweek'] : false;

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

?>
<?php
    $additional_query = $show_thisweek ? '&year=' . date('Y') . '&w=' . date('W') : '';

    query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page='.$postsNum.'&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC' . $additional_query ); ?>
        <div class="widget-aligned">
        <h3 class="box-title">Popular Articles</h3>
        <div class="blog-entry">
            <ol>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><h4 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end widget-aligned -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

  /*Saves the settings. */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = stripslashes($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['postsNum'] = stripslashes($new_instance['postsNum']);
        $instance['thisweek'] = 0;
        if ( isset($new_instance['thisweek']) ) $instance['thisweek'] = 1;

        return $instance;
    }

  /*Creates the form for the widget in the back-end. */
    function form($instance){
        //Defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('title'=>'Popular Posts', 'postsNum'=>'','thisweek'=>false) );

        $title = htmlspecialchars($instance['title']);
        $postsNum = htmlspecialchars($instance['postsNum']);


        # Title
        echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '">' . 'Title:' . '</label><input class="widefat" id="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('title') . '" type="text" value="' . $title . '" /></p>';
        # Number of posts
        echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('postsNum') . '">' . 'Number of posts:' . '</label><input class="widefat" id="' . $this->get_field_id('postsNum') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('postsNum') . '" type="text" value="' . $postsNum . '" /></p>';  ?>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked($instance['thisweek'], 1) ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thisweek'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('thisweek'); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thisweek'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Popular this week','Aggregate'); ?></label>
        <?php
    }

}// end AboutMeWidget class

function PopularWidgetInit() {
  register_widget('PopularWidget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'PopularWidgetInit');

?>
```

How can I change this script so that it will count the past 7 days rather than posts from last Monday?

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-of-past-7-days-broken-down-by-cateogry

Comment: That thread explains how my setup is currently (posts from a specific day) when I am looking for a solution to count posts from the past 7 days.

Comment: I think the link Diego chatted should do the trick.  The first piece of code does what you're after - it adds a filter to return posts in the last seven days.  Might be worth removing the filter after the `get_posts` call just to be safe.  I don't think it'll be easy to do without a filter, just because of the way `WP_Query` works.

Comment: @Hobo Can you kindly post an answer demonstrating how you mean? Ideally, can you please alter my current code so that I understand this approach better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on your request and Diego's link, something like this (untested) should work.

First, add a function to your class that'll filter the rows selected by `query_posts`:

```
function this_week_filter($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

Second, add the filter (if necessary) before calling `query_posts`:

```
if ($show_thisweek) {
    add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'this_week_filter'));
}
```

And just to be on the safe side, remove it after calling `query_posts` (so it doesn't affect any other queries you run):

```
if ($show_thisweek) {
    remove_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'this_week_filter'));
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
<?php class PopularWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    function PopularWidget(){
        $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Displays Popular Posts');
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300);
        parent::WP_Widget(false,$name='ET Popular Widget',$widget_ops,$control_ops);
    }

    function this_week_filter($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

  /* Displays the Widget in the front-end */
    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? 'Popular This Week' : $instance['title']);
        $postsNum = empty($instance['postsNum']) ? '' : $instance['postsNum'];
        $show_thisweek = isset($instance['thisweek']) ? (bool) $instance['thisweek'] : false;

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        if ($show_thisweek) {
            add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'this_week_filter'));
        }


        query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page='.$postsNum.'&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC'); ?>
        <div class="widget-aligned">
        <h3 class="box-title">Popular Articles</h3>
        <div class="blog-entry">
            <ol>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li><h4 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4></li>
            <?php endwhile; endif;

            if ($show_thisweek) {
                remove_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'this_week_filter'));
            }

            wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end widget-aligned -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }
```

The rest of the code's unchanged.

It's probably possible to move the `remove_filter` call earlier (straight after `query_posts`), but I can't test right now.

Comment: I just tested your code and unfortunately it did not return any posts at all. Is there a typo in your code? Can you kindly run a test on your own server? Thank you for the respond regardless.

Comment: Damn.  I assume you left the remaining code, you didn't just replace all yours with mine?

Comment: Oh yeah definitely, I kept the remaining code past `echo $after_widget;` What do you think? Do you have a chance to run it on your system?

Comment: Sorry - was missing a closing quote around the date.  You'll need to update the `this_week_filter` function.  Told you it was untested ;-(

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing your code guys. I'm using the updated code in the answer however when I tick 'Popular this week' the widget doesn't display any content. Do I need to update something in the code?